# NSSplitView not resizing subviews after dynamically adding a subview

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nssplitview

I'm trying to add a subview to my NSSplitView, so that my vertical split view goes from

```
---------

view A (height = 100)

---------
```

to

```
----------

view A (height = 50)
----------
view B (height = 50)

----------
```

I thought this would be straightforward, but neither view's heights are changing after adding a new subview to the split view.

Here's what I am doing to add view B as a subview:

```
splitView?.addSubview(NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100)))
splitView?.adjustSubviews()
```

This causes splitViewDidResizeSubviews to be called, but both view heights remain at 100 and overlap each other with no divider shown.

I uploaded a sample project showing the issue: https://duke.box.com/s/f50y2pjjbf3ib0y60c7yr5h3p3nicok7

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Ugh, so there's a checkbox in IB for the NSSplitView called 'Arranges All Subviews' which was introduced in OS X 10.11.  After checking this my views are sizing correctly.

OS X 10.11 also introduced the addArrangedSubview and insertArrangedSubview:atIndex methods

Extremely annoying since this doesn't even seem to be listed in the [NSSplitView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/) docs.

Comment: That is annoying. Did you file a bug report on the missing documentation?